# Laravel queues and jobs

Tags: php, laravel, daemon

I am writing a job say Process X that will take x items from the database and transform them according..

Basically, when dispatching the jobs I chunk items and tag them with a bucket id then pass that bucket id to the job which will then process items with bucket id x.
 At the job level, i am torn between querying all items with bucket id x and loading them to memory or working on them one by one query one and finishing with it then querying the other.

Or is there a better way I can do this? My aim is to find the most optimal way avoid trips the database as much as possible and at the same time do not use too much memory

Comment: The method you is exactly how i would do it, but i would dispatch another job after a specific time lets say 2 minutes which process all items from another bucket.

Comment: Well, everything depends on the size of your objects, I would say, but remember,  _testing is knowing_.

Comment: @RazaMehdi yeah, hadn't considered the options of dispatching another bucket later